# Sql Server Compact Multiple Files

Tags: sql-server-ce

Are there any restrictions with SQL Sever CE in the number of files to be used?  I have an application written sometime ago that used a now obsolete database and want to upgrade it.  I want to keep the same approach for installation without needing to do a complicated database install and CE seems to fit that need.  The file size limit is 4GB, right?  Under that restriction, I would need to create one file for data and another for images.  Would this work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, that would Work, but there can be no referential integrity across database files.

Comment: Hey Erik!  What would be wrong with creating a separate data base file to house "procedures" ina simple text format? Basically, get the SQL statement from one then use it on the real one.  Might take a little longer in processing but it provides better security thana plain text file, especially of the database is password protected and encrypted.  Plus, changes to sripts can be done by simply modifying the text, instead of having to release new code.

Comment: Why not simply include the procedures as an emebedded ressource with your app?